# Simple form submit with JQuery with constraints on required fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Using `$(this).closest('form').submit();` doesn't quite play nice with required fields, as it will force a submit irrespective of form contents. Is there a simple way to confirm specific fields are filled before submitting a form?

```
<form action="./submit.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" required="required"/> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="bar" required="required"/> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="baz" required="required"/> <br/>
    <div class="box" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();">Submit</div>
</form>
```

My best thought would be to gather all form elements with `.attr('required','required')`, iterate through them and confirm some value exists, but is there a better/shorter method?

Comment: are you using html5 validations

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I am, but using `.closest('form').submit();` ignores it.

Comment: why use div instead of an input type="submit" ? also using "required" attribute html5 will validate it automatically.

Comment: @JohnLouieDelaCruz, `.box` has other modifying classes that I wish to change with JQuery depending on the form. I might append a `.red` to it to make the box red when form is incomplete, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use check the `checkValidity` method

```
var $form = $(this).closest('form');
if (!$form[0].checkValidity || $form[0].checkValidity()) {
    $form.submit();
}
```

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this).closest('form');
  if (!$form[0].checkValidity || $form[0].checkValidity()) {
    $form.submit();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="x" required />
  <br />
  <input name="y" required />
  <br />
  <input name="z" />
  <br />
  <a href="#">Test</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Arun's answer is as-ever spot on but I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. By changing you submit button to be an actual HTML button like you can style it however you like *and* it fixes your submit/validation problem.

```
<form action="./submit.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" required="required" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="bar" required="required" /><br/>
    <button class="box" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b7ocknzf/3/) with JS-less validation and crazypants button styles.